# Point cloud registraction via ICP that robust to large number of outliers

Tags: point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I'm trying to perform point cloud registraction via ICP(Iterative closest point) and I use PCL library's `pcl::IterativeClosestPoint` algorithm.

But seems that it's not robust to large number of outliers. Seem area that is circled with red pen is "pulls" point cloud toward it and point cloud's not aligned perfectly.
[image]
[image][image]

Is there any robust variant of ICP algorithm (or other registration algorithm) that can handle it?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30559556/point-cloud-library-robust-registration-of-two-point-clouds/37179345#37179345), I describe a pipeline that could be useful for your case. Basically you need to find inlier correspondences between both point clouds and get/apply an initial transformation. Then you can use ICP for a fine refinement of your registration.

Comment: I tried 3D matching approach like here http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/template_alignment.php but result even worser (maybe it's beacuse I have two point clouds that are near the plane shape?). Also is there an option to restrict transformations in case of ICP and 3D matching?

Comment: Also I found this paper usefull http://lgg.epfl.ch/~ichim/registration_tutorial_ram_2015/data/registration_paper_tutorial_ram_2015.pdf

Comment: I may have another solution for your scenario that is more straight-forward. Since you can approximate your clouds to a plane, try to apply a [planar segmentation](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/planar_segmentation.php) and then apply directly ICP to the inliers (points that will lie on the plane). That should achieve a good registration.